# calling java component with multiple java classes from Mule

Tags: mule

I am using Anypont Studio 5.3.0 and server runtime 3.7.0. I want to invoke a main() method from my component. Application is developed using Maven, SpringBoot and JPA. It sits in the jar file and have the following structure.

> com
>
> > package
>
> ```
>           Application.class (with main method)  
>  another package
>            Other classes
> ```
>
> lib

```
       other jars
```

> META-INF

```
           persistance.xml
           MANIFEST.MF
```

Org

```
  springframework boot loader and other spring classes.
```

when file arrives with file pattern that I detect with mule  polling component I would like to invoke Java component in mule flow that has main class and all the supporting classes.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

did you mavenize your Application? If yes, you can add that as a dependency in your mule project pom, which is also mavenize. But you need to make sure that the jars are added in your maven repository i.e. execute first "mvn clean install" to your java application. Otherwise, add the jars in you build path. When you are able to do those, you can create a spring bean or create a java component in mule where they could call your class with main() method.

Answer (score 0):

I never came across this kind of production scenario where there is a need to call main method of java class in enterprise application. Are you sure you have only main method to access other classes, it should have initialize, spring way of injection etc. Simple answer to you question, create a mule java component and override onCall method to call Application(class).main. I will never do this kind of stuff [for sure it will give more problems based on what is being written in main method]. In general we will use main method invocation in desktop application. if possible work on (or let the application team to work on) jar file to have better initializing options